# How to install latest LTS version with Laravel installer?

Tags: laravel

I want to install latest **LTS** version with laravel installer, Which arg should i pass to `laravel new ?` ? The latest LTS version is: `v6.19.1`

Comment: If you want to use a specific version you will have to use composer, you cannot pass a version number to the laravel installer.

Comment: I dont want to pass specific version, I want that laravel installer find the latest LTS version which is 6.19.1 something like : `laravel new blog --lts`

Comment: LTS or not, it is still a specfic version, there is no option for this in the laravel installer, it can only install the latest version that your system supports.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel projectName "6.*"
```

Comment: I said laravel installer https://github.com/laravel/installer

Comment: You can't with laravel installer, as you can see from the installer source code: https://github.com/laravel/installer/blob/master/src/NewCommand.php . There is no argument related to what you need
Also, they perform the same operation just with a different syntax, I don't understand why you should be so reluctant to use a different option

Comment: As you can see at row 84, the laravel installar will simply execute the same composer command that I posted under the hood: https://github.com/laravel/installer/blob/master/src/NewCommand.php#L84